# How to assign virtual auto-increment rank with limit of 4?

Tags: mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group, rank

Simply put, I would like rid to order my pid.

Instead of creating an extra table called 'rank' with 4 rows I would like to be able to just attach a virtual rank that gives the same effect. My rank is just there to give a position to my tags. Since I have 4 tags per id I would have a value of 1-4 enumerating those tags.

This way I won't have to manually put in the same numbers over and over again.

My tables:

```
   people            tags_rel               tags           rank

id   | etc     id | pid  | tid | rid      id | tag          id
-----+-----    ---+------+-----+----      ---+--------      --
2345 |         1  | 2345 |  2  | 1        1  | bread        1
2346 |         2  | 2345 |  3  | 2        2  | water        2
2347 |         3  | 2345 |  1  | 3        3  | bear         3
               4  | 2345 |  6  | 4        4  | milk         4
               ---+------+-----+----      5  | hotdogs
               5  | 2346 |  3  | 1        
               6  | 2346 |  4  | 2
               7  | 2346 |  2  | 3
               8  | 2346 |  5  | 4
               ---+------+-----+----
               9  | 2347 |  6  | 1
              10  | 2347 |  1  | 2
              11  | 2347 |  4  | 3
              12  | 2347 |  5  | 4
               ---+------+-----+----
```

My query:

```
SELECT p.id as pid, t.tag as tname, tr.tid as trid, r.id as rank
FROM people AS p
RIGHT JOIN tags_rel AS tr ON tr.pid = p.id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON tr.tid = t.id
LEFT JOIN rank AS r ON tr.rid = r.id
```

MySQL expected results:

```
> +--------+------------+--------+------+
> | pid    | tname      |  trid  | rank |
> +--------+------------+--------+------+
> | 2345   | water      |    2   |   1  | 
> | 2345   | bread      |    1   |   2  |
> | 2345   | cereal     |    3   |   3  |
> | 2345   | milk       |    4   |   4  |
> | 2346   | cereal     |    3   |   1  |
> | 2346   | milk       |    4   |   2  |
> | 2346   | water      |    2   |   3  |
> | 2346   | hotdogs    |    5   |   4  |
> | 2347   | chocolate  |    6   |   1  | 
> | 2347   | bread      |    1   |   2  |
> | 2347   | bread      |    4   |   3  |
> | 2347   | bread      |    5   |   4  |
> +--------+------------+--------+------+
```

I am using rank as position. So whatever tags are attached to pid I would like to show by first position. Since the tags are different for each pid they would have different positions. I may want to call tname=water by rank=1 and it would display all the 'water' tags in position 1 only.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `a better way of showing the query`?

Comment: Forget that.. too much confusion. If someone knows the answer please help.

Comment: So wait, are you saying you *don't* want to have ranks assigned to each tagging, like you have shown?

Comment: Well I would like to have the same effect you see now with the rank table but using a virtual rank ex: @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rank

Comment: Can you explain why water is ranked first?

Comment: Sure, I am using rank as position. So whatever tags are attached to pid I would like to show by first position. Since the tags are different for each pid they would have different positions. I may want to call tname=water by rank=1 and it would display all the 'water' tags in position 1 only.

Comment: Then how come `5  | 2345 |  4  | 1 = milk` is ranked 4? This tag is with rid=1

Comment: sorry that wasn't the right pid. I want the rank to just number each pid so I can choose all from rank x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to remove the `rid` column from your `tag_rel` table, and have an automatically genarated position field in your query instead. The "position" of a tag in your case can be understood as the number of entries in the `tag_rel` table that have been added for a specific `pid`. In other words: all entries in the table with the same `pid` and an `id` that is equal or lower, assuming `id` is an autoincrement field.

I think this can be done as follows. Mind you, it may not be the most efficient code in the world:

```
SELECT id, pid, tid, (
    SELECT count(*) from tags_rel t2 where t2.pid = t1.pid and t2.id <= t1.id
) AS rid
FROM tags_rel t1;
```

I'm not entirely sure this will work, as I only have mysql 3 here, which doesn't do subqueries like this. I think it will though.

If you may have more than 4 tags linked to a person, but you want only the first 4 tags for each person, you can now use:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    [the above query]
) WHERE rid <= 4;
```

This having been said, I think in almost all situations you might as well just `order by pid, id` and then adding the rank numbers in your output medium. But then, I don't know your situation.

I think the most important thing is: is this what you meant? If so, hopefully some people on here will be able to provide you with the best answer to your question.

EDIT:

For your current query, this would amount to:

```
SELECT p.id as pid, t.tag as tname, tr.tid as trid, (
           SELECT count(*) 
           FROM tags_rel AS tr2 
           WHERE tr2.pid = tr.pid and tr2.id <= tr.id
       ) AS rank
FROM tags_rel AS tr
LEFT JOIN people AS p ON tr.pid = p.id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON tr.tid = t.id
```

assuming you don't need the `where rid <= 4` part. (By the way: the `tr.tid as trid` kind of suggests you want to select `tags_rel.id` instead of the `tags_rel.tid` (== `tags.id`). I'm not sure if that's what you mean; if not, it might be better to select `tr.tid as tid` (or just `tr.tid`).)

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly what I meant. But how do I implement it with my current query and which way is more efficient/faster?

Comment: Ok, I put it into your current query. As for efficiency: as said, I suspect it might be fastest to only add the positions visually in your final product, but that depends on your situation. By the way: if you always add the entries in the tags_rel table 4 at a time (like in your example), so they always have consecutive ids, you could also use `(1 + id - (SELECT Min(tr2.id) FROM tags_rel AS tr2 WHERE tr2.pid = tr.pid)) AS rank`. That would be a lot less robust, but I think it would also be faster...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works just like I want it. :)

Comment: last thing.. how do I call a `WHERE rank=1` the query doesn't recognize the rank column

Comment: Hmm... I think you should use `HAVING rank = 1`, or if that fails you could try `SELECT * FROM (SELECT p.id etc) WHERE rank = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

make use of order by and limit

```
order by pid,rank
limit 4;
```

Comment: Of course it won't. You did not put in the complete question at the first edit ... moody

Comment: that wasn't an attack so please don't take it that way. I'm just hoping someone out there can answer my question. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you want.

```
SELECT p.id AS pid, t.tag AS tname,tr.tid AS trid,tr.rid AS rank
FROM 
people AS p JOIN tags_rel AS tr ON tr.pid = p.id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON tr.tid = t.id 
order by pid,rank;
```

If you just want the 'water' tags in position 1, you would add "WHERE tname = 'water' AND rank = '1'" before "ORDER BY".

Note that there is actually no need for your rank table. If you want the 'rid' field to be restricted to only 4 values, just make it an enum datatype.

Comment: how would I add that exactly? When I try this: ALTER TABLE  `tags_rel` ADD  `rank` ENUM(  '1',  '2',  '3',  '4' ) NOT NULL; I get a value of 1 on all rows. Also it says enum is not ideal for numbers..

Comment: ALTER TABLE `stuff`.`tags_rel` CHANGE COLUMN `rid` `rid` enum('1','2','3','4')  ;

Comment: that's interesting but I'll still have to select them manually each time I define a tag for an id.

Comment: So what you want is an autoincrement field with a limit of 4?

Comment: yes it should auto increment rank for the number of tag per id